# I can't figure out how to get rid of whitespace

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site and I can't figure out white there is whitespace showing up. I have my page wrapper div and everything else set to width: 100%; My header and footer and using the full width of the screen, but my other content isn't using all the width of the page. I think it has something to do with positioning.

Also, my jsfiddle is screwing up my header. I'm using PHP for that and it's working fin on my machine. Please ignore that.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WH5jZ/

```
.pageWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#mainPage {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d101/Lee45276/food1_zps6cb55c3d.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EDIT: I figured it out but I cannot post an answer:

I figured it out. I had to remove the padding in the nav and footer.

old

```
nav, footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    width: 100%;
     padding: 1% 2.5%;
}
```

new

```
nav, footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the main body content

**ORIGINAL**

```
/***************
CONTENT
***************/

.contentDiv, #bulkdel {
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5% auto 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Your width is set to `95%` that is why its not using `100%`

Change it to

```
/***************
CONTENT
***************/

.contentDiv, #bulkdel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5% auto 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Other than that I think everything else looks fine on your page

Comment: #bulkdel isn't being used right now. And .contentDiv is the black div in the middle - it doesn't affect the background img (the taco plate).

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you have added padding to the footer which is pushing it out past the rest of the content. I'm sure removing the padding will solve your problem.

EDIT:
I see you updated your question with the answer.

In other words, change this:

```
nav, footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 2.5%; /* remove this */
}
```

to this:

```
nav, footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    width: 100%;
}
```